# Attempt to present UIAlertController whose view is not in the window hierarchy with localnotification

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying to present AlertView once the user clicks on the local notification. The AlertView has options of cancel or ok.

```
extension ViewController:UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate{


    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        print("Tapped in notification")
        if(defaults.object(forKey: "alertOn") != nil){


            // Create the alert controller
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Some text", message: "Some text again", preferredStyle: .alert)


            // Create the actions
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
                UIAlertAction in

            }

            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel) {
                UIAlertAction in
            }

            // Add the actions
            alertController.addAction(okAction)
            alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

            // Present the controller
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }


func triggerNotification(){

        print("notification will be triggered in five seconds..Hold on tight")
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "SomeText"
        content.body = "Some more text"
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.init(timeInterval: 5.0, repeats: false)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier:requestIdentifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as! UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request){(error) in

            if (error != nil){

                print(error?.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
```

It should show me the alertview with option to ok or cancel a request. Instead its showing me message **UIAlertController whose view is not in the window hierarchy**

When I put the alertview in viewdidapear it works fine but when I put it in userNotificationCenter my AlertView not get attached to the main view.

**Brief View of Code**

```
extension ViewController:UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate{
          func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

         Present UIAlertView

        }
}

ViewController{

Call to notification when app is in background 
triggerNotification()

triggerNotification(){
 Definition 
}
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try this

```
func currentTopViewController() -> UIViewController {
    var topVC: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window?.rootViewController
    while topVC?.presentedViewController {
        topVC = topVC?.presentedViewController
    }
    return topVC!
}
```

and present the VC as

```
let currentTopVC: UIViewController? = self.currentTopViewController()

currentTopVC.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please walk me through where shall I put the first code snippet?

Comment: add  in before `func triggerNotification(){`

Comment: Thank you. It works! How ever the alert view asks to add a annotation on mapview and annotation is not showing up in map(When pressed Ok in alertView). I believe as its not able to add itself to the topview?

Comment: this works perfect...in any situation! tested in XCode 9.1 and Swift 4

Comment: @xhinoda - Thanks my bro