# Attempt to present OTPViewController on UIAlertController whose view is not in window

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I wrote this code so that the viewcontroller changes from loginscreenviewcontroller to otpviewcontroller.

```
function createAlert() {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Please wait\n\n", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let spinnerIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .whiteLarge)
    spinnerIndicator.center = CGPoint(x: 135.0, y: 65.5)
    spinnerIndicator.color = UIColor.black
    spinnerIndicator.startAnimating()
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    Alamofire.request(".....").responseData { response in
       switch response.result {
           case .success:
               self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
               self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "OTPSegue", sender: self)
       }
    }
}
```

but it gives me an error

```
Attempt to present <Junkart.OTPViewController: 0x79769c80> on <UIAlertController: 0x79b5fe00> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

alert controller does close but there is no change in view controller.

Please help.

**UPADTE 2**
Ok. So I am able to change to the other viewController but the alert view goes to the top before the new view controller animates and takes the whole screen.

Comment: hi this answer could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28451295/push-view-controller-after-dismissing-presented-view-controller

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/42218707/3901620

Comment: createAlert is this called in ViewDidLoad ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is pretty exhaustive.

You need to dismiss alert view and **then** perform 
segue with the new view controller:

```
alertController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "OTPSegue", sender: self)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You dismiss the current view controller before present new view controller. That's wrong. Remove following line instead self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: what should I do then? please elaborate

Comment: remove following line:
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)